# My external hard drive got virused and I found this very suspicious javascript file. Can someone analyze this file for me?

Tags: javascript, virus

My 750 GB external hard drive got virused.  When I helped my friend get a copy of visual studio for his laptop and plugged my external hard drive into it, nearly 95% of my files got hidden pretty quickly and was replaced by shortcut files aka .lnk files (To top it off, that was 366 GB worth of data from school projects).  Before the entire hard drive was turned into .lnk files, I quickly unplugged my external hard drive.  I plugged my external back into my pc and run the ff. command prompt command to un-hide the files hidden:

```
@echo off
attrib -h -s -r -a /s /d G:\*.*
PAUSE
@echo on
echo DONE!
```

This G: location is what my pc recognize my external hard drive before and during the virus attack, after running the batch command above, my pc now recognizes my external hard drive with E:.

When the files got visible again, I saw all the missing folders into a hidden folder named "Drive" and I quickly moved out all the files I remember being originally here.  What I fished out of my hard drive was the ff. files:

- A windows batch file executing a javascript file located at "G:\Drive\808\exmjxt.js" which I'm pretty sure I did not ever create.
- A javascript file named "exmjxt.js"

Now, I tried to open the javascript file mentioned above using notepad++ and this is the code I saw in it (there is only 4 LINES in this code, but for some reason, the first line of "var a = ...." line apparently contains 84906 characters fitted into that first line):

(Code too long, it has more than 85,000 characters, here is a pastebin link instead)

[Pastebin link for the javascript virus code](http://pastebin.com/g3WEmUY4)

If you're a person who knows javascript, please help me out with analyzing this javascript file, idk what this code does.

Last time I got infected with a shortcut virus, the virus digged up my yahoo email address from the saved cookies in my browser and sent the email to some shady website and the next minute, I was sent quite a lot of NSFW and 18+ advertisements in the form of an email for the next 6 months -_-

Comment: Disagree with the current closevote stating this belongs on superuser.com. The OP is specifically asking a coding question.

Comment: @DamienOvereem I'd say he's asking a question about *code*, not *coding*.

Comment: @Keith He is talking about the code in pastebin. The code up top is what he used to un-hide the files.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to decode and read through that entire code, but as a lot of it is just obfuscated with what looks like unicode, you could try to decode the unicode and tidy it up with automatic indentation, and read it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS worm that infected the HDD is a variant of JS/BONDAT. What it does is the following:
Copy itself to startup folder, connect to command and control server, run through loop of spreading to external drives.

Comment: I've search about the JS/BONDAT worm variant.  Now I know why my anti-virus didn't detect this worm.  I re-installed my anti-virus into a new drive (not C:\ drive) and run the antivirus to do a full scan.  Now it detects the virus and it got removed from my pc and flash drives.  It seems that it stops .exe files related to anti-virus programs in C:\ drive so that it can spread out.